# Pass parameter from popup window to parent on different domains

Tags: javascript, popup

I open popup window from Javascript that redirects to different domain. User performs few steps there and at the end popup is closed and the result is passed back to Javascript. I've tried calling `window.opener.myfunction` but it doesn't work with different domains.

Is it possible to achieve that? I think problem is similar to Facebook connect, where in Javascript I get result of the authentication performed in popup window.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for different domains because the `Same-Origin` policy applies and restricts access of scripts executing from a different domain. What you could do is pass the parameter as part of a query string argument:

```
Popup Window Opens -> http://mydomain/popup?name=value
http://mydomain/popup?name=value -> http://externaldomain/target?name=value
```

Through which the other domain would pass back the same parameter:

```
http://externaldomain/target?name=value -> http://mydomain/result?name=value
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. However I cannot pass parameter like that. Parameter value received from popup has to be send POST to the server. I think the only way is to do that from Java script.